# Geting started with Solr on WebLogic

Tags: solr, weblogic, weblogic12c

Can anyone recommend a good article or shed some light on deploying Solr to a WebLogic container. The examples are all Jetty based and I am running into some fundamental issues deploying the war.

I have downloaded the latest from http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/lucene/solr/4.6.1 and extracted the archive. I have then pushed the war from dist/solr-4.6.1.war to a WebLogic container and deployed the war from the console.

On startup, Solr is throwing an expception that it cannot locate a suitable looging jar and also that no configuration file exists.

My question is, how or where should I configure a logical home path for Solr in which to place required libraries, schema files, etc?

Comment: What have you tried, what exact errors do you get? There is tons of information out there about running in weblogic: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrWeblogic http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/general/137183

Comment: I have WebLogic running inside a Vagrant VM that I am using for testing. I have pushed the solr war to that VM and run through deploying it to WebLogic using the admin console.

Comment: I have WebLogic running inside a Vagrant VM that I am using for testing.
I have pushed the solr war to that VM and run through deploying it to WebLogic using the admin console.
During startup I see the following root exceptions:

SEVERE: null:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
and
INFO: /u01/app/oracle/local-dev-oracle/solr/solr.xml does not exist, using default configuration

I would like to tell Solr to use a specific location on the server and put config or required jars in e.g.
/opt/solr/conf/schema.xml
/opt/solr/lib/*.jar

Comment: Ended up needing to define environment vars when launching the container which resolved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solr has its own app server, jetty.  There isn't any (good) reason to use an external app server with Solr.

The link to the Apache site above references WebLogic 10.  WebLogic is now on version 12.  That tells you how long it's been since anyone from the Apache community needed to upgrade the docs for WebLogic. The other links go to generic WebLogic info so that other reply probably came from someone with the Oracle marketing department.

There are no compelling reasons to rip out Jetty and run Solr on another app server.  You are just looking for trouble.

Comment: In my past project Jetty had issues with size of http headers (used for faceted search), I had to tune and configure size of headers, and I find that odd as according j2ee, the size of headers is unlimited. Once I moved SOLR to WL, no extra configuration was needed. I would go with SOLR and WL. Also, timezone on Jetty is not aligned with anything, while on WL it picks up WL timezone.